# wrapping function in deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm trying to create a queue that I can wrap the objects passed in with deferred in order to make the objects that have a Model and Action properties (Action is just an ajax call) finish before calling the next.

```
        var promises = [];

        _.each(this.List, (model) => {   // List is just an object that has a Model and Action property
            var wrapperFunc = (() => {
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                model.Action();
                deferred.resolve();

                promises.push(wrapperFunc);
            });
        });
```

The problem is, model.Action() just gets called.  Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Your code just calls Deferred resolve without waiting for the Action to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but unanswered still.

Calls like model.Action() do not block unless you specifically set the async option to false in your ajax call. Instead of blocking, the ajax call will return a deferred object. With jQuery you can call jQuery.when(deferred).then(callback), or deferred.done(callback). Callback is a function which will be run after the ajax call is complete.

A quick google on Stack Overflow for deferreds should answer a lot of your questions (if they haven't already been answered, I know I'm posting one year later).